# SQL Server Always on Clustering, Not able to create listener

Tags: sql-server, cluster-computing, alwayson

I am quite new to SQL Server Clustering with Always on feature so I really sorry if I am asking some silly question. 
I have setup the windows cluster and was able to set up the always on feature on SQL Server. But when I am trying to create the 
Availability group listener, SQL Server is giving me the error

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Create failed for Availability Group Listener 'AGTestCluster'. 
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60+((SQL11_RTM).120210-1917+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+AvailabilityGroupListener&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> The WSFC cluster could not bring the Network Name resource with DNS
>   name 'AGTestCluster' online. The DNS name may have been taken or have
>   a conflict with existing name services, or the WSFC cluster service
>   may not be running or may be inaccessible. Use a different DNS name to
>   resolve name conflicts, or check the WSFC cluster log for more
>   information. The attempt to create the network name and IP address for
>   the listener failed. The WSFC service may not be running or may be
>   inaccessible in its current state, or the values provided for the
>   network name and IP address may be incorrect. Check the state of the
>   WSFC cluster and validate the network name and IP address with the
>   network administrator. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 19471)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.2100&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=19471&LinkId=20476

I have checked with my windows administrator, he is saying that I have create object permission.

Can anyone please let me know the steps through which

1. I can add the listener
2. If I am not able to add the listener then please provide me the steps to verify the permission that needs to be there to setup the listener

**Notes**

1. I am not a AD administrator, so I need to find out the permission without any AD thing involved
2. The listener IP address and Name has been given by my administrator only
3. The firewall is off on both the server

Please help

Thanks
Atul

Comment: use DBA site http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You will need to access AD/DNS or work with someone who does. The listener requires a computer object in AD. If this object, also known as the VCO, is not prestaged and/or the proper rights given, the network name cannot be brought online, thus the failure. So you will need to work with your AD admins. And also check if there are any computer object/DNS conflicts as well. Again, you'll need to work with the right folks.